# Swift OpenAPPI Post request to upload a file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, post, openapi-generator

I am trying to figure out how to use the new OpenAPI generator for swift.

I have this valid schema or yaml file.

```
openapi: "3.0.3"
info:
  title: BcNotioUpload
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://prod.server.co
    description: "prod server"
  - url: https://stagin.allocations.gbct.io
    description: "Staging server"
    
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT

security:
  - bearerAuth: [APIKey]
  
paths:
  /telemetry/upload:
    post:
      operationId: uploadRide
      summary: Send CSV file to the servers.
      description: Bla bla bla bla bla
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                fileName:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
            description: callback successfully processed
```

And in the implementation of my swift code I use this based on the Get example. I am not certain where the put the filename in this.

Body is accepting a Data and I need to send a CSV file and it't name.

{edit} Also I am not sure if I need to have an additional property for the file binary or if the

```
fileName:
   type: string
   format: binary
```

take care of both keys, or do I need to change this to

```
fileName:
  type: string
  format: binary
file:
  type: object
  format: binary
```

in postman my body would be like this
[image: Postman Body of request]

Updated:

```
if let fileData = data {
        let transport: ClientTransport = URLSessionTransport()
        let client = Client(serverURL: try! Servers.server1(), transport: transport)
        Task{
            let resp = try? await client.uploadRide(.init(body: .binary(fileData)))
            switch(resp){
            case .ok(_):
                // Switch over the response content type.
                print("Upload Ok")
                self.delegate?.onExportEnd(error:nil)
            case .undocumented(statusCode: let statusCode, _):
                // Handle HTTP response status codes not documented in the OpenAPI document.
                print("Upload Error")
                showAlert(title: "Danger Danger Will Robinson!!", msg: "Something did not work")
                errorHandler("Upload Failled")
                print(" undocumented response: \(statusCode)")
            case .none:
                print("Upload none ?")
                //errorHandler("Upload ???")
            }
        }
```

For the data part do I need to change `.binary(fileData)` to something like`.binary(Data(from: ["file.name":"theNameOf TheFile", "file":fileData)` ?? or do I have to put the file name in some other parameter in the uploadRide(.init(...)) ?

---

I have no example of any guide or any clue on how to use the uploadFile()
Does any one know how I can use the Client to send my file or if any one as a link to more in-depth swift documentation then the small get Cat example apple gave us??

Comment: sadly this is not ready yet. https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator/issues/36

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this:

```
let response = try? await client.uploadRide(body: .multipartForm([
      .file(.init(payload: .init(body: .init(fileData)))),
      .name(.init(payload: .init(body: .init(fileName))))
]))
```

Where I assume that:

- `fileName: String` with key `name`
- `fileData: Foundation.Data` with key `file`